# Getting error as -> Could not parse the remainder: '-2021' from '2020-2021'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I need to display some information based on the condition that the "fiscal year" should be "2020-2021".

Following is the condition, I am writing in **Django template**:-

```
{% if awp.Fiscal_year == 2020-2021 %}
```

I tried putting 2020-2021 in quotes but that didn't work, as follows:-

```
{% if awp.Fiscal_year == '2020-2021' %}
```

After after writing the fiscal year in quotes, the data is not rendering while without quotes, it is producing the error -> **django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '-2021' from '2020-2021'.**

Type of fiscal year (data type) is -> **<class 'pmisminema.dataEntry.models.Fiscal_year'>**

Here is how it is defined in **models.py**:-

```
Fiscal_year = models.ForeignKey( Fiscal_year, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1,)
```

Class for the "Fiscal_year" is as follows:-

```
class Fiscal_year(models.Model):
    ackFlag = models.SmallIntegerField(default=DEFAULT_ID)
    approveFlag = models.SmallIntegerField(default=DEFAULT_ID)
    createdTime=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    modifiedTime=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=DEFAULT_ID)
    Financial_Year = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Financial_Year
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Instead of it, can filter the data using database query?

Comment: Can you share your view? Usually it is better to filter at the database side, not the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to do the following changes in the if condition here (after looking at the class of "Fiscal_year"):-

```
{% if awp.Fiscal_year.Financial_Year == '2021-2022' %}
```

It worked fine after using this condition !!